# confusing behavior of emacs-style keybindings in bash

Tags: bash, keyboard-shortcuts, emacs, readline

Bash offers many useful `emacs-style keybindings` for simple commandline editing. For example, <kbd>Ctrl+w</kbd> deletes ("kills") word left from the cursor.

Another keybinding, <kbd>Alt+d</kbd> is supposed to be a "mirror" of the first one. It is supposed to delete a word right from the cursor.

However, I have noticed, these two keybindings do not act completely symetricaly. Whereas <kbd>Ctrl+w</kbd> treats `foo.bar` as one word, <kbd>Alt+d</kbd> treats it as two words

Even more annoyingly, `# echo` are two words for <kbd>Ctrl+w</kbd>, but one word for <kbd>Alt+d</kbd>.

Is there some logic in this? Is there some reason why they don't treat words in the same way?

**Is there any way for me to change this?**

I am using bash on `Debian Wheezy`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Different bash commands use different notions of word. Check the description of each command in the [manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Readline-Killing-Commands).

[`C-w`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Readline-Killing-Commands) kills to the previous whitespace. `M-DEL` (usually <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>BackSpace</kbd>) kills to the previous word boundary where words contain only letters and digits (the same as `M-b` and `M-f`), and `M-d` kills forward similarly.

Bash uses the Readline library to process user input, and can be configured either via [`~/.inputrc`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Readline-Init-File) or via the [`bind`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-bind) builtin in `~/.bashrc`. You can bind a key to a different [readline command](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bindable-Readline-Commands) if you wish. You can also use `bind -x` to bind a key to a bash functions that modifies the `READLINE_LINE` variable.

For example, to make `M-d` kill a shell word, bind it to [`shell-kill-word`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-shell_002dkill_002dword-_0028_0029) in your `.bashrc`:

```
bind '"\M-d": shell-kill-word'
```

To make `M-d` delete a whitespace-delimited word, there is no built-in function, so you need to write either a macro or a shell function. Since there is no motion command that goes by whitespace-delimited words, you need a function at least for that part.

```
delete_whitespace_word () {
  local suffix="${READLINE_LINE:$READLINE_POINT}"
  if [[ $suffix =~ ^[[:space:]]*[^[:space:]]+ ]]; then
    local -i s=READLINE_POINT+${#BASH_REMATCH[0]}
    READLINE_LINE="${READLINE_LINE:0:$READLINE_POINT}${READLINE_LINE:$s}"
  fi
}
bind -x '"\ed": delete_whitespace_word'
```

To make `M-d` kill a whitespace-delimited word is more complicated because as far as I know, there is no way to access the kill ring from bash code. So this requires a function to find the end of the portion to kill, and a macro to follow this by the actual killing.

```
forward_whitespace_word () {
  local suffix="${READLINE_LINE:$READLINE_POINT}" 
  if [[ $suffix =~ ^[[:space:]]*[^[:space:]]+ ]]; then
    ((READLINE_POINT += ${#BASH_REMATCH[0]}))
  else
    READLINE_POINT=${#READLINE_LINE}
  fi
}
bind -x '"\C-xF": forward_whitespace_word'
bind '"\C-x\C-w": kill-region'
bind '"\ed": "\e \C-xF\C-x\C-w"'
```

All of this would be a lot easier in zsh.

Comment: do you know how to modify `~/.inputrc`, so that `Alt-D` will use white space as a word boundary?

Comment: @MartinVegter I don't think you can do it with readline alone, but you can do it in bash, see my edit. If you want fancy command line edition, you'll be better off in zsh.

Comment: after having used your hack for some time now, I find it absolutely great. There is only one small problem: When I press `M-d` to delete a whitespace-delimited word, it deletes the word **including** the whitespace after it. I have to manually add the space, otherwise the two commands will be joined together. Would there be any way of changing that in the code?

Comment: @MartinVegter This makes sense. My code was actually deleting the first space character after the word, which was just weird. I've changed my approach in `delete_whitespace_word`, it should now work like in Emacs and like you want.

Comment: sorry, my mistake. Actually it works perfectly.

Comment: I have encountered small problem: I have added the "delete_whitespace_word ()" code to my /etc/profile.d/readline.sh. All works OK if I login with login shell (i.e. SSH, su). But when I log in from my terminal emulator (Terminator) the file probably does not get loaded and therefore it does not work. Further, if I change terminator to "run command as login shell", I get an error: "/etc/profile.d/readline.sh: line 8: bind: warning: line editing not enabled"

Comment: @MartinVegter You put that code in the wrong file. It should be in your `.bashrc`. Make sure that your `.bash_profile` sources `~/.bashrc`, otherwise the bindings wouldn't be available in a login shell (bash's init file management is screwy).

Answer (score 4):

Readline already has `vi-fword` and `vi-bword` which use whitespace as word boundaries so there's no need for Gilles's `forward_whitespace_word` function.

`vi-fword` followed by `unix-word-rubout` (`\C-w`) deletes a whitespace-delimited word backward (including trailing spaces).

```
bind '"\eb":vi-bword'
bind '"\ef":vi-fword'
bind '"\ed":"\ef\C-w"'
```

`vi-backward-word` is an alias to `vi-bword`, `vi-forward-word` is an alias to `vi-fword`, `vi-backward-bigword` is an alias to `vi-bWord`, and `vi-forward-bigword` is an alias to `vi-fWord`.

Comment: This sounds great, but how can I test it? Where should I put your code? the lines in my `/etc/inputrc` have different format, i.e. `"\e[1;5D": backward-word`. (there is no `bind` infront)

Comment: and BTW, for what key combination does "\ef" stand ? What should I press? `Alt` + something ?

Answer (score 1):

This is a result of the way [readline](http://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/rluserman.html#SEC6) treats "words". <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>d</kbd> is a shortcut for `kill-word`:

> Kill from point the end of the current word, or if between words, to the end of the next word. *Word boundaries are the same as those used by M-f* (forward-word).

Word boundaries in `forward-word` are defined thus:

> Words are composed of letters and digits.

Whereas <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>w</kbd> is a shortcut for `unix-word-rubout`:

> Kill the word behind point, *using white space as a word boundary*.

So, to use your example of `foo.bar`, the first command treats the string as two "words" separated by a `.`, whilst the second sees no whitespace so treats it as a single "word".

Comment: is there any way to change it? (other than recompiling my own version of Bash). Can this be changed in `.bashrc`, for instance ?

Comment: @MartinVegter Yes, you can modify any of the bindings in `~/.inputrc`.

Comment: could you please suggest how I can modify my `~/.inputrc`, so that `Alt-D` acts on whole words (same as `Ctrl-W`) ?

Comment: @MartinVegter You can use `~/.inputrc` to rebind any of the readline functions; to change the functions themselves, you'd have to hack the source...

Comment: OK, but what line shall I put into my `~/.inputrc`, so that `Alt-D` acts on whole words (whitespace separated)