# How to transpose command line arguments with emacs keybindings?

Tags: bash, line-editor

Using Bash, with emacs keybindings set, the transpose-words keybinding (`M-t`) doesn't transpose arguments, but "words" (by its own definition of words).

So if I have this:

```
vimdiff project-number-One/Vagrantfile project-number-Two/Vagrantfile.old
```

and my cursor is between the first and second argument when I enter <kbd>option</kbd><kbd>t</kbd>, I instead end up with

```
vimdiff project-number-One/project Vagrantfile-number-Two/Vagrantfile.old
```

which is obviously not what I want.  How can I transpose arguments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In bash, different commands have different notions of words. [`C-w`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Readline-Killing-Commands) kills to the previous whitespace, but most other commands including `M-t` use punctuation-delimited words.

With the cursor between the first and second argument, `C-w C-e SPC C-y` will transpose the two words.

If you want to bind a key to transposing whitespace-delimited words, it's more complicated. See [confusing behavior of emacs-style keybindings in bash](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/150578/confusing-behavior-of-emacs-style-keybindings-in-bash/150591#150591). Here's some minimally tested code.

```
transpose_whitespace_words () {
  local prefix=${READLINE_LINE:0:$READLINE_POINT} suffix=${READLINE_LINE:$READLINE_POINT}
  if [[ $suffix =~ ^[^[:space:]] ]] && [[ $prefix =~ [^[:space:]]+$ ]]; then
    prefix=${prefix%${BASH_REMATCH[0]}}
    suffix=${BASH_REMATCH[0]}${suffix}
  fi
  if [[ $suffix =~ ^[[:space:]]+ ]]; then
    prefix=${prefix}${BASH_REMATCH[0]}
    suffix=${suffix#${BASH_REMATCH[0]}}
  fi
  if [[ $prefix =~ ([^[:space:]]+)([[:space:]]+)$ ]]; then
    local word1=${BASH_REMATCH[1]} space=${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
    prefix=${prefix%${BASH_REMATCH[0]}}
    if [[ $suffix =~ [^[:space:]]+ ]]; then
      suffix=${suffix#${BASH_REMATCH[0]}}
      READLINE_LINE=${prefix}${BASH_REMATCH[0]}$space$word1$suffix
      READLINE_POINT=$((${#READLINE_LINE} - ${#suffix}))
    fi
  fi
}
bind -x '"\e\C-t": transpose_whitespace_words'
```

This is all easier in zsh…

Answer (score 1):

If your cursor is there:

```
vimdiff projectOne/Vagrantfile projectTwo/Vagrantfile
                              ^
```

Press Alt + BTTBBTFTBBTT

---

Or simple:

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd>, insert a whitespace and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Y</kbd>

Comment: Thanks, but if I can't have a command that handles whole arguments, then it'll actually be a lot more complicated than that.  I updated the examples to be closer to real life, with punctuation.

Comment: Your simple approach seems to work, except that I think you meant `control` (or `Ctrl` on Windows keyboards) rather than `Alt`.

Answer (score 1):

For a quick and simple solution add this to your inputrc (choose suitable keys for yourself):

```
"\e\C-b": shell-backward-kill-word
"\eh": shell-backward-word
"\e\C-f": shell-forward-word
# Swap the preceding two arguments (control + alt + t)
"\e\C-t": "\e\C-b\eh\C-y"
# Swap the preceding argument with the next (control + alt + p)
"\e\C-p": "\e\C-b\e\C-f\C-y"
```

In case of `shell-*` versions of these functions [words are delimited by non-quoted shell metacharacters](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Commands-For-Moving.html).

> **[metacharacter](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Definitions.html)**
>
> A character that, when unquoted, separates words. A metacharacter is a space, tab, newline, or one of the following characters: ‘|’, ‘&’, ‘;’, ‘(’, ‘)’, ‘<’, or ‘>’.

Note: The cursor has to be after the second argument before pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>, so it effectively pushes the argument before the cursor towards the beginning of the line.

```
$ true foo/bar.xyz even/without\ quotes.ok "too/too far.away"
                                                             ^
$ true foo/bar.xyz "too/too far.away" even/without\ quotes.ok
                                     ^
$ true "too/too far.away" foo/bar.xyz even/without\ quotes.ok
                         ^
```

Note: The cursor has to be after the first argument before pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd>, so it effectively pulls the argument before the cursor towards the end of the line.

```
$ true "too/too far.away" foo/bar.xyz even/without\ quotes.ok
                         ^
$ true foo/bar.xyz "too/too far.away" even/without\ quotes.ok
                                     ^
$ true foo/bar.xyz even/without\ quotes.ok "too/too far.away"
                                                             ^
```

Comment: Works! Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 0):

You need to press `BTTBBT` instead of a single `T`.

Comment: Thanks, but if I can't have a command that handles whole arguments, then it'll actually be a lot more complicated than that.  I updated the examples to be closer to real life, with punctuation.