# How do I swap the two last command line arguments?

Tags: bash, readline, line-editor

```
$ ln -s ./dir/target.txt /path/to/source.txt{cursor here}
```

How do swap file typed filenames in command line? <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> swaps words, not filenames, resulting in `ln -s ./dir/target.txt /path/to/txt.source`.

Ideally the solution should also interpret `"filenames with quotes.txt"` correctly.

Can it be done by some readline and/or bash configuration, or by some clever use of existing shortcuts?

Comment: [How to transpose command line arguments with emacs keybindings?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/162559)

Answer (score 7):

Partial answer based on [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/162573/17594). `{}` denotes cursor:

```
$ ln -s ./dir/target.txt /path/to/source.txt{}
```

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> (repeat this if once is not enough, but don't <kbd>Backspace</kbd>)

```
$ ln -s ./dir/target.txt {}
```

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+{<kbd>←</kbd>,<kbd>←</kbd>,<kbd>←</kbd>,<kbd>←</kbd>}, <kbd>→</kbd>, <kbd>→</kbd>

```
$ ln -s {}./dir/target.txt
```

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd>, <kbd>Space</kbd>

```
$ ln -s /path/to/source.txt. {}/dir/target.txt
```

Ready.

Comment: Based on your answer and the link you provide, I've just learned a whole heap more that I didn't know about bash :) Where does one find these gems?

Comment: Easier way to get to before the first path: ctrl-a (start of line), ctrl-right or alt-f twice (forward word).

Answer (score 5):

I think this can be done using bang commands:

```
!:0 !:2 !:1

!:0 word designator 0, the zeroth word.
!:n The nth word.


man bash
```

Word designators, section.

Comment: Only giving a code snippet is not enough without explanation.

Comment: I type `!:0 !:2 !:1` after `/path/to/source.txt`, but nothing happens. Obviously, I don't want to execute the incorrect command line.

Comment: `Word Designators
       Word  designators  are used to select desired words from the event.` -> Events? Is it that annoying (`bash: !": event not found`) thing that gets into my way and drops my command line when I forgot to escape `!`?