# Is it possible to (re)define what readline (embedded in bash) defines as a word?

Tags: bash, readline

Many of the special Readline constructs allow the user to edit
the command line in various ways. For instance, certain keystrokes
allow moving forward a *word*. A *word* is defined to be what bash
itself defines it to be.

Is it possible to set bash parameter(s) so that Readline defines
a *word* to be something different other than what bash
normally defines it to be? Say, any sequence of non-whitespace characters?

Comment: No, but in bash, you can [define functions that behave like readline's except for a different notion of word](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/150578/confusing-behavior-of-emacs-style-keybindings-in-bash/150591#150591).

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, the definition what is a word depends on the current locale settings.

The readline man page (bash uses readline for input handling) says:

> Words are composed of alphanumeric characters (letters and digits).

Answer (score -1):

Bash splits words by the `$IFS` variable, see https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Word-Splitting.html.

Note, that word selection (i.e. by doubleclicking the word) is configured in your terminal's settings.

Comment: That is *not* the same way Readline splits words. For example, `backward-word` will move to a hyphen within a word, but that's not part of `IFS`.