# How to revert from searching to original command

Tags: bash, keyboard-shortcuts, command-history

Following the instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1030182/how-do-i-change-bash-history-completion-to-complete-whats-already-on-the-line), I edited by .bash_profile to enable the up and down arrows to autocomplete what I have typed in the shell based on previous commands.

I added to my .bash_profile:

```
# bind history search to up and down arrows
if [[ $- == *i* ]]
then
    bind '"\e[A": history-search-backward'
    bind '"\e[B": history-search-forward'
fi
```

This is great, but I want the down arrow to return to my original text if I can't find the command I'm looking for.

For example, say I have three previous commands:

- `ls -l`
- `ls -al`

Now, I type `ls` with the intention of autocompleting it to `ls -a`.

I hit the up arrow, which (with my current implementation) autocompletes my text to `ls -al`. I hit the up arrow again, which autocompletes my text to `ls -l`. At this point, I decide that I won't find the command I'm looking for. If I press the down arrow, the text changes to `ls -al`, but **pressing the down arrow again doesn't change anything.** I want pressing the down arrow to return to my original text (`ls` in this case) after I've reached the most recent command in the history.

I would really appreciate it if anyone could help me out or point me in the right direction.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Ctrl+K` will kill the text from the cursor to the end of line. so If you haven't moved the cursor, `Ctrl+K` will give you (ie, effectively
revert to) your original text

Comment: Is there any way to set it up that down arrow maps to `history-search-forward` _unless_ there is nothing forward, in which case the down arrow would map to `Ctrl+K`?

Comment: @ZachKirsch You can bind a key to a bash function which checks the line content. See http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/150578/confusing-behavior-of-emacs-style-keybindings-in-bash/150591#150591 for an example. It's cumbersome to call a readline function afterwards, I think it would be simpler to call `fc` to retrieve history items. Mixing shell functions and line editor commands is easier in zsh.